# How do I find the 'temp' directory in Linux?

Tags: c++, linux

How do I find the 'temp' directory in Linux? I am writing a platform neutral C++ function that returns the temp directory. In Mac and Windows, there is an API that returns these results. In Linux, I'm stumped.
­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Answer (score 32):

Check following variables:

- The environment variable `TMPDIR`
- The value of the [`P_tmpdir` macro](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Temporary-Files.html#index-P_005ftmpdir-1608)

If all fails try to use the directory `/tmp`.

You can also use `tempnam` function to generate a unique temporary file name.

Comment: is there a standard (POSIX or whatever) which specifies this order of doing things? I've seen it in several places so I'm sure it's right but I was wondering if there was an authoritative statement anywhere.

Answer (score 19):

Edit: Fair point from the commenter. `tmpnam` isn't a good choice these days; use `mktemp`/`mkstemp` instead.

*Historical answer: Be POSIX compliant, and use tmpnam (which will give you a full filename in a temporary location).*

Comment: The linux man page I have for tmpnam says in its BUGS section: "Never use this function.  Use mkstemp or tmpfile"

Comment: I'm getting that same warning on the mktemp linux [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mktemp.3.html). And I don't have `mkstemp` or `tmpfile` commands (on OSX).

Comment: mkstemp doesn't help you figure out what directory to use.

Comment: This does not tell you *where* the path template you provide should start.

Answer (score 12):

Use the value of the $TMPDIR environment variable, and if that doesn't exist, use `/tmp`.

Answer (score 11):

The accepted sequence, specifically from a GNU standpoint, is:

1. Check the environmental variable **TMPDIR** (*getenv("TMPDIR")*) only if
   the program is not running as **SUID/SGID** (*issetugid() == 0*)
2. Otherwise use **P_tmpdir** if it is defined and is valid
3. and finally, should those fail, use **_PATH_TMP** available from paths.h

If you are adding an extension or module, check to see if the core provides a function for this purpose.  For example, PHP exports php_get_temporary_directory() from main/php_open_temporary_file.h.

Answer (score 1):

In standard c, you could try: P_tmpdir

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could find it using the environment variable `TMPDIR`.
However it is not always defined.

The question is not about creating a temporary folder but find the existing one.

```bash
dirname "$(mktemp --dry-run)"
```

This should give you the top most temporary folder.