# Command to get the "temp folder" in Linux

Tags: linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find the 'temp' directory in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31068/how-do-i-find-the-temp-directory-in-linux)

GetTempPath will return the temp folder path in Windows. Is there any equivalent command to get the temp folder path in Linux?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31068/how-do-i-find-the-temp-directory-in-linux

Answer (score 3):

On linux there are 2 fixed locations: `/tmp` - wiped on reboot, and `/var/tmp` - not wiped. Some application also respect `TMP` environment variable. See also `mktemp` command.

Comment: mktemp() function generates a unique temporary file name. My aim is to create a temp file with specified name in temp folder.

Comment: I didn't said mktemp function.  I said mktemp command - which is not answer to your question but have some related info.

Comment: Different programs do different things, because there's nobody to enforce a specific method, but `TMPDIR` is the environment variable most often used (including by the `mktemp` command).