# Giving VersionPress write permissions via ssh on bitnami WP ami running on EC2 instance

Tags: wordpress, git, amazon-web-services, ssh, ec2-ami

Thanks in advance for your patience and support helping me with this issue. I can normally work around most problems by reading online, but when it comes to linux and ssh I cant - it's too complex. No two explanations seem the same.

The problem is this:

I launched an EC2 instance using the bitnami wordpress ami (i think its an ami?) and everything works great.

Im super excited about this new wordpress project called VersionPress, link below.

I managed to install git and get a tick in that box. Now I need to satisfy the plugin's requirements for write permission on several folders.

I've been reading up on chmod, and checking out what permission are currently in place using ssh, but can not, for the life of me, make sense of it.

The info on what VersonPress needs is here: http://docs.versionpress.net/en/getting-started/installation-uninstallation

If we take for example the plugins own folder /versionpress, I can navigate to it and see the current permissions using ls:

drwxr-xr-x 7 bitnami bitnami ... versionpress

So I'm like ok, I suppose I'd better give group write permissions. But, no version of the chmod command I write will execute and even then, it's only one of the folders that I need to change.

UPDATE: I added '~' and got chmod working on the /versionpress dir

As a next step I tried to change rights on /wordpress dir. This was initially unsuccessful until I applied command with Sudo.

VersionPress still reports it does not have the correct permissions however.

Error msg: VersionPress needs write access in the site root, its nested directories and the system temp directory. Please update the permissions.

END UPDATE

Anyone experienced this, got VersionPres up and running on EC2 or with any advice to move me forward?

Thanks.

Comment: "no version of the chmod command I write will execute" Please show exactly what you are trying and what the exact error message is please.

Comment: Hi Mark B.
I was writing something like chmod 775 /apps/wordpress/...
I found that by inserting ~ I could pass the correct path for a folder and now chmod 775 works on the /verisonpress folder.
Then i tried it on the /wordpress folder and got 'operation not permitted'. 
Thinking I'm smart I ran sudo chmod 775 on /wordpress. It seemd to work but I had a short freakout when I could no longer browse /wordpress (as bitnami user i guess). I ran the command again and it seems ok. 
Permissions on /wordpress are now drwxrwxr-x
Versionpress still says has a warning message tho - but I'm out of chars.

Comment: Versionpress message: VersionPress needs write access in the site root, its nested directories and the system temp directory. Please update the permissions.

Comment: You should edit your original question with all these details instead of adding them as comments. It appears you've only added full write permissions to the bitnami user and every user in the bitnami group, so I can see why VersionPress is still complaining. Perhaps you could try adding whatever user VersionPRess uses to the bitnami group.

Comment: Thanks for the advice on editing Mark - been a while since I came here.

I was thinking something similar about users. However, I don't know which user VersionPress uses. Is there a way to check that?

Also - I need to find this system temp directory - any idea where that is?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31068/how-do-i-find-the-temp-directory-in-linux

Comment: If it is running, you can see the process info, including user, via the `ps` command.

Comment: Thanks again mark - found /wordpress/tmp which I hope is the right one.

Comment: ps isn't turning up much that makes sense to me. ps -ef turns up more results. php-fpm master process is being run by root - think that's what I'm after?