# File creation and writing is failled in a device location

Tags: android, c++, c, java-native-interface

I want to create a file in my device by using JNI program.and i created a file in the location of **data/local/hello.txt** by using the code

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_com_maacrofuzzyn_acsianiac_samplelibrary_MainActivity_Register(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject ob) {

int i = 0;

    FILE* file = fopen("/data/local/hello.txt","w+");
    if (file != NULL)
    {
        fputs("HELLO WORLD!\n", file);
        fflush(file);
        fclose(file);
    }
```

but, i cant create a file in the location **tmp/hello.txt** by using the same code. i think this is something permission problem. how can i solve this problem and create a file in that location... please help me.

Comment: `tmp/hello.txt` or `/tmp/hello.txt` ?

Comment: Also [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31068/how-do-i-find-the-temp-directory-in-linux) article might be of interest for you.